# Translate icon appears but no translations exist

Tags: localization, multi-site

I have a site in development that i replicated from another project.
The other project was multi lingual and had some fields that were translated.
This new site does not require any translations but the transalte icon is still appearing next to some fields which is very annoying.

Any idea how I can safely remove these?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **Translation method** to **Not translatable** for each field displaying the unwanted translation icon, in the field's settings page.

[image: Screenshot showing how to change a field's translation method from its settings page]

It may be a tedious task if you have a lot of fields.

Comment: My problem is no translation methods drop down is showing

Comment: What type of field is it ?

Comment: Ah i just worked out of i save each field then craft gets the message and some db adjustment takes place and the translate icons disappear. Might see if i can write a quick script to save all fields.....cheers:)